# PCL: How does textureMeshwithMultipleCameras() handle occlusion?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

From the kinfu samples, i notice:

https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/tools/standalone_texture_mapping.cpp

That the textureMeshing function with multiple cameras seems to exist. However, there doesn't seem to be any input to the depth image. Hence, how is this function able to handle occlusion?

Answer (score 1):

See the function:

```
tm.textureMeshwithMultipleCameras(mesh, my_cams);
```

It has as inputs the mesh and the camera positions and directions.
For explanation of the functions see:

https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/46cb8fe5589e88e36d79f9b8b8e5f4ff4fceb5de/surface/include/pcl/surface/texture_mapping.h

and

https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/46cb8fe5589e88e36d79f9b8b8e5f4ff4fceb5de/surface/include/pcl/surface/impl/texture_mapping.hpp

The occlusion functions use Octree.